# Sort 2 dimensional array from largest to smallest string size based on first string in secondary array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So say I have an array that looked something like this:

```
var array = [["This should be last", 1],
             ["This should be first I think", 1],
             ["This is the middle one", 1]];
```

The second value of each secondary array, which in this case is always 1, is arbitrary to the sorting. Now obviously `.sort()` will be of no direct use here. (Or maybe it will?)

I need to sort the array from largest to smallest string size. So after the sorting process it should look like this:

```
var array = [["This should be first I think", 1],
             ["This is the middle one", 1]
             ["This should be last", 1]];
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out how to use .sort() and made my own solution.. Fml. `function sortFunction(a,b) {
 if (a[0].length < b[0].length) {
  return 1;
 }
 if (a[0].length > b[0].length) {
  return -1;
 }
 return 0;
}`

Comment: You don't have to return -1, 0 and 1. Any positive or negative number can do => function(a, b) { return a.length - b.length; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `sort` you can provide your custom comparative function:

```js
array.sort(function(a,b) {
  return b[0].length - a[0].length;
});
```

In ECMAScript 6, it can be simplified to

```js
array.sort((a,b) => b[0].length - a[0].length);
```

Comment: Wow thank you. Since I'm using ECMAScript 6 anyways this is an even better solution than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

As sort uses a sort function you can just look into the the first element of the array, and sort by it:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
var aStr = a[0];
var bStr = b[0];
return bStr.length - aStr.length;
});
```